# Custom sorting in post columns by ACF Pro Select Field

Tags: custom-post-types, php, advanced-custom-fields, columns

I'm adding a custom column to the admin display for a custom post type. The custom column should display the selected options from an ACF Pro select field. Instead, it always triggers as containing the value, which suggests to me that instead of pulling only the selected options for each post, it's pulling all available values for the ACF Pro select field.

I'm just... not sure how to solve this. What am I getting wrong here?

```
add_action( 'manage_asgallery_posts_custom_column', 'asgallery_new_column', 10, 2);
function asgallery_new_column( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if( $column_name == 'featured_posts' ) {
        $a = get_field_object('field_5dbcb72cad947', $post_id); 
        $a_value = $a['value'];
        //$case_study = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'case_study_category' );
        if(strpos($a_value, 'Repair') !== false) {
            echo 'Repair'; 
        }
        else { echo 'None'; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_field()` instead of `get_field_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to simplify your conditional check.

```
add_action( 'manage_asgallery_posts_custom_column', 'asgallery_new_column', 10, 2);
   function asgallery_new_column( $column_name, $post_id ) {
     if( $column_name == 'featured_posts' ) {
     $a_value  = get_field('field_5dbcb72cad947', $post_id); 
      if($a_value === 'Repair') {
        echo 'Repair'; 
       }
     else { echo 'None'; }
}
}
```

You want the_field itself, not the_field_object.